# "Comprehend" vs "Interpret" vs "Understand"

Tags: differences, terminology

What is the difference between "Comprehend", "Interpret", and "Understand"?

Here are the definitions that I referred to, from Cambridge Dictionary-

Comprehend- to understand something completely.
Interpret- to decide what the intended meaning of something is.
Understand- to know the meaning of something that someone says.

So, according to these definitions, "to comprehend" means "to understand" but completely, so, is it that understanding something is not knowing something completely but comprehending something is knowing it completely, and interpreting something is associating meaning to something after knowing about it, I am here a bit confused...

Comment: Have you checked the corresponding dictionary definitions of each? If you have, you should include what you've discovered in the question (to avoid others pointing out something you're already aware of).

Comment: Please edit to explain your doubts. Otherwise your question will soon be closed. What have you found when you looked up these words in the dictionary?

Comment: It should be clear from the definitions you cite that "interpret" is different from the other two, but "understand" and "comprehend" can be very close in meaning.

Comment: These words are so vague in meaning that one might conclude people didn't really know what thoughts actually were.

Answer (score 0):

You read something.

Comprehending and understanding it are very similar.

Interpreting it is very different. You and I can read the same sentence and based on a number of factors interpret it very differently.

All three lead into another and work together. You can read something and "understand" it, but you can't "comprehend" it without "interpreting" it because "interpretation" is a piece of it. Without "interpretation" you cannot "comprehend" because the concept isn't "complete" in a sense.

Now where "misinterpretation" comes into play is where it's tricky. Good luck with that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).